# How many matrix combinations is this?

Tags: matrix

Input Matrix:

```
  A B C D E 
A 1 - - - -
B - 1 - - -
C - - 1 - -
D - - - 1 -
E - - - - 1
```

```
"-": arbritary values
"1": locked "1" value (diagonally locked, ref below)
```

Output Matrix (one possible example after some arbitrary optimization based on the arbitrary values in the matrix):

```
  C E A D B 
C 1 - - - -
E - 1 - - -
A - - 1 - -
D - - - 1 -
B - - - - 1
```

Sidenote: in case it matters, in the output matrix, the `-` values have remained the same according to their locations, i.e. cell `B,C` in the output matrix has the same value as cell `B,C` in the input matrix.

Sorting rules:

- If an A-E row is moved, the A-E column needs to move also, so that the "1" remains diagonal top left to bottom right (exactly like in the output matrix example).

Questions:

1. How many possible combinations are there? Is it as simple as `5 (A-E) * 5 (A-E) = 25`?
2. What would be a good algorithm approach for an exhaustive run where all possible combinations are considered. `FOR` loop on rows, nested with a `FOR` loop on columns maybe?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Since column order must be same as row order, there are really only 5 items (A, B, C, D, E). For number of combinations of 5 items, it is $5! = 120$ combinations.
2. An algorithm could be:

   ```
   items = [A, B, C, D, E]
   num_items = items.length

   function choose(items):
       if items.length is 0:
           yield items

       for i in 0 up to items.length:
           # choose i-th item, and append recursively with remaining items
           # Generates:
           #   A, B, C, D, E
           #   A, B, C, E, D
           #   A, B, D, C, E
           #   ...
           #   E, D, C, B, A
           yield items[i] + choose(items - {items[i]})

   for combo in choose(items):
       do_something(combo)
   ```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139677/discussion-between-stef-and-preferred-anon).